# How to automate a file conversion xwm to mp3 with xwmaencode.exe using bat file

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, converters

the code that is required to run this is:
xwmaencode.exe .xwm  .
I wanna make a .bat file that can allow me to drag and drop a file or convert all of the .xwm files within the current folder to .mp3 preferrably

an explanation of each part would be good as well, i have no clue how .bat files operate, and i have limited knowledge on CMD syntax, but i can manage

Answer (score 1):

if you don't mind file.xwm.wav (and there are utilities out there that'll remove the .xwm*), what i did was basically taken from PNGOUT.exe's help examples:

```
for %i in (*.xwm) do xwmaencode %i %i.wav
```

in this case, you don't have any files with spaces, but if you did, you'd do

```
for %i in (*.xwm) do xwmaencode "%i" "%i".wav
```

*powershell might, but i have no idea

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the exact code for the xwmaencode code line, for I don't know the tool but a quick look at the readme of xwmaencode tells me that this should work:

```
@ECHO OFF
:TOP
IF (%1) == () GOTO END
ECHO Processing %1...
REM you will need to modify the next line
C:\Path\To\xwmaencode.exe %1 %1.mp3
SHIFT
GOTO TOP
:END
ECHO All files processed!
PAUSE
```

When you d&d a file onto a bat the complete path to the file is passed to the bat as a parameter: `batfile.bat path:\to\dragged\file\file.xyz`

If you d&d several files it looks like this:

`batfile.bat path1 path2 path3 ... pathN`

You can access the first parameter (meanst the path to the first file) with %1, to the second with %2, etc. By calling SHIFT you move %1 from the first paramater to the second. So the code is in a loop calling xwmaencode.exe with %1 and shifting %1 to the next parameter after each execution. It stops as soon as %1 is empty.

Comment: aint workin, i think it just adds .mp3 to the end of the file name _and_ extension. and it fails to create another file or even take the original file and convert it.

Answer (score -1):

The above ought to work, but variables in batch files need to be defined with two percent signs, not one.
(E.g., %%a instead of %a)
Also, taking away the @ECHO OFF line will let you see if the command worked or any errors it gives you.

Comment: Parameters passed to a batch file are only prefixed with one percentage sign. And variables in general are also just prefixed with one percentage sign, but additionally suffixed with one. What you mentioned are FOR counter variables, but you probably confused all of that.